# How do i write a basic program that asks for a number and then prints out the sum from one to the number?

Tags: python

What is wrong with this? I need to get it to sum negative numbers too.

Result = int(input('Enter a number: ')) M = (result) For I in range(m): Result = result + i Print(result)

Comment: Python is a language for which formatting matters quite a bit. Unless you provide us with your code properly formatted, we have no idea what your problem could be. As it stands, you would get an indentation error.

Comment: Also Python is case sensitive - `'for' != 'For'` and `'Result' != 'result'`, for example... I suspect you're using something which auto-capitalises each line; if that's what you're actually trying to *write code in*, stop immediately.

Comment: @IbrahimApachi stop trying to edit with code formatting. I rejected your previous attempt for a reason; unless you know what the OP's actual indentation is, it's not helpful.

Comment: @IbrahimApachi seriously, though; how is fixing *the very problems the OP is likely asking about* help anyone?! The code you're changing it to **does work**, rendering the question completely redundant! It's good to help fix people's formatting, but not when it changes the meaning of their question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably an indentation error, but your for loop should read,

"for i in range(m):"
not "for I in range(m):"

The print function should be in lowercase letters as well.

Python is case sensitive so make sure all of your variables are matching up.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for you.

```
n = int(input())
result=0
for i in range(n):
    print "Enter number"
    num = int(input())
    result+=num
print"The sum is", result
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixes it for negative input values; it still has a problem if input is 0.

```
upto = int(input("Enter a number: "))

sign = abs(upto) // upto      # +1 or -1
upto = abs(upto)

total = sign * sum(range(upto + 1))

print("The result is {}".format(total))
```

Comment: Why did you accept the edit?! It fixes several of the problems the OP is presumably asking about!